# InputStreamReader buffering

Tags: java, character-encoding, buffer, inputstream

In the [InputStreamReader class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html)  it is declared that:

> To enable the efficient conversion of bytes to characters, more bytes
>   may be read ahead from the underlying stream than are necessary to
>   satisfy the current read operation.

what does this statement mean ?
Does the implementation buffer some input data ? 
If so, after the use of an InputStreamReader the current position, on the stream we are reading, may not be what we expect...

Comment: _may not be what we expect_ It should be what you expect if that's what the API is telling you it does.

Comment: Correct.  You should not expect to read some bytes with the Reader and then go back to reading bytes where you expect.

Comment: Unless you were trying to implement your own stream reader, the "position" in the original stream doesn't mean anything to you, since your interface to it is through the stream reader API, which is implemented well enough such that the above statement should not impact you.

Comment: as @LouisWasserman noted, my question is centered on whether or not we can go back reading bytes after using an InputStreamReader.

Comment: And the answer is no, not reliably.

Comment: @LouisWasserman you should make that a Stack Overflow answer, so that I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have read the documentation correctly, and correctly deduced that you cannot reliably go back to reading the underlying input stream and expect to know where you are in the stream.